# JPA: make two fields as unique key or let jpa update but not insert

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

This is my Entity:

```java
@Entity(name = "order_info")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    // the user who create this order
    @OneToOne
    private User user;

    // the product of this order
    @OneToOne
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Product product;

    // money
    private Integer monkey;
```

I requirement is :

User + Product should be a unique key, each user can only create one order for a product.

Bu my problem is:

```java
    @Autowired
    private OrderCrudRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void save(){
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(2);

        Product product = new Product();
        product.setId(1);

        Order order = new Order();
        order.setMoney(33);

        order.setProduct(product);
        order.setUser(user);

        repository.save(order);
        System.out.println(JSONObject.toJSONString(order, true));
    }
```

sometimes, I want to **update a record** if  but not save a record. unfortunately, I can not find update in SpringDataJPA.

I want to force JPA to update database if there is already a record in database which has some user and product value.

How can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To specify a unique key, just add the annotation on top of the entity class:

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"userId", "productId"})})
```

In order to do the update, you must first find the managed entity and then update the entity with whatever value you want. For example:

```
Order order = orderRepo.findById(id);
order.setUser(...)
order.setProduct(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no saveOrUpdate in JPA.What I do is to search a record and in case found update it using explicit Update statment using entityManager.